# Calculate cumulative sum from beginning of year to filter selection

Tags: powerbi, dax, powerbi-desktop

I have two tables

1. Calendar - Contains columns for year, quarter, YearQuarter
2. Sales - contains columns for Entity sold, sale price, date of sale, quarter of sale, year of sale.

I have a filter in my dashboard for Year and Quarter. I would like to create a measure that calculates the cumulative sum of sales from the beginning of the selected year to the selected quarter.

e.g. if Year = 2020, and Quarter = Q3, the measure should calculate the sum of sales from the beginning of 2020 until the end of Q3 2020.

[image]
[image]
[image]

Answer (score 0):

If you had a well-formed date table, you could use time-intelligence functions [DATESYTD](https://dax.guide/datesytd/) or [TOTALYTD](https://dax.guide/totalytd/) as explained in [The hidden secrets of TOTALYTD](https://www.sqlbi.com/blog/marco/2018/08/10/the-hidden-secrets-of-totalytd/).

However, your calendar table doesn't qualify, so you need to do things a bit more manually.

```
Sales YTD =
VAR SelQtr = SELECTEDVALUE ( Calendar[Quarter] )
RETURN
    CALCULATE (
        [Sales],
        ALLEXCEPT ( Calendar, Calendar[Year] ),
        Calendar[Quarter] <= SelQtr
    )
```

This removes any calendar filtering except for the year and filters for quarters up to the selected quarter.